# Specifying different GNUmakefile for GNU make command

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I have two GNUmakefiles in my directory as follows,

GNUmakefile &
GNUmakefile2

Could someone please let me know the command I have to use, if I have to let the "make" command to process "GNUmakefile2" instead of "GNUmakefile".

I used the below command,
**make -f GNUmakefile2**

but in that case, I am getting the following errors,

*This is gnustep-make 2.6.1. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.*

*make[1]: *** No rule to make target `internal-master-tool-all'.  Stop.*

*make: *** [internal-all] Error 2*

I think it is considering GNUmakefile as makefile (when I use make with -f command), so it is checking for rules in GNUmakefile.

At present what I am doing is I am renaming the required file (which I want, make command to execute) to "GNUmakefile". And I am not getting any errors while executing "make" command, but I don't think this is the correct solution.

Please let me know which command I need to use for this scenario. Thanks for your help.

After checking Beta's solution (i.e.,but that makefile is invoking Make a second time, and the second Make process is probably reading GNUmakefile) what I have done is I renamed existing "GNUmakefile" to "GNUmakefile3".

So at present in my directory the following makefiles are present:- "GNUmakefile2" & "GNUmakefile3".

And then I executed the following command:- $ make -f GNUmakefile2

I recieved the below errors,

This is gnustep-make 2.6.1. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
make[1]: GNUmakefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `GNUmakefile'.  Stop.

make: *** [internal-all] Error 2

Please let me know what is the problem here

Comment: `make -f GNUmakefile2` is the correct command, but that makefile is invoking Make a second time, and the second Make process is probably reading GNUmakefile, because that is the default. Can you show us GNUmakefile2? We may have to modify it in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Please find the below contents of GNUmakefile2,  

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make  
LIBRARY_NAME = libHelloWorld  
libHelloWorld_HEADER_FILES = HelloWorld.h  
libHelloWorld_HEADER_FILES_INSTALL_DIR = HelloWorld  
libHelloWorld_OBJC_FILES = HelloWorld.m  
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/library.make  
  
Please let me know what is the problem here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Beta: I modified the question based on your inputs please check that.

Comment: This confirms my theory; one of these makefiles contains a command like "$(MAKE) -f GNUMakefile internal-master-tool-all". Please show us `common.make` and `library.make`.

Comment: Hi,
Please find the below link for common.make:- http://pastebin.com/gKNXz7LH

Please find the below link for library.make:- http://pastebin.com/H6YMjkUu

Please check it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile includes two huge makefiles from the FSF. The second, `library.make`, contains this rule:

```
ifeq ($(GNUSTEP_MAKE_PARALLEL_BUILDING), no)
# Standard building
...
else
# Parallel building. ...
internal-library-all_:: $(GNUSTEP_OBJ_INSTANCE_DIR) $(OBJ_DIRS_TO_CREATE)
    $(ECHO_NOTHING_RECURSIVE_MAKE)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) ...
endif
```

and the first, `common.make` contains this assignment:

```
# The default name of the makefile to be used in recursive invocations of make
ifeq ($(MAKEFILE_NAME),)
  MAKEFILE_NAME = GNUmakefile
endif
```

So try either **`make -f GNUmakefile2 GNUSTEP_MAKE_PARALLEL_BUILDING=no`** or **`make -f GNUmakefile2 MAKEFILE_NAME=GNUmakefile2`**, and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. "make -f GNUmakefile2 MAKEFILE_NAME=GNUmakefile2" command worked. Other command (i.e., make -f GNUmakefile2 GNUSTEP_MAKE_PARALLEL_BUILDING=no) didn't worked. Still I am confused why "make" command is getting called recursively. Once again thanks for your help.